# Getting rows that contain key1 and don't contain key2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that look like this:

- Table 1 (main table):

  ```
  item_id (item_id, item_name) // item_id set to primary 
  row1    (1,       "item 1")
  row2    (2,       "item 2")
  row3    (3,       "item 3")
  ```
- Table 2 (linking table):

  ```
  item_keywords (ikid, #item_id, #keyword_id) // ikid is set to primary 
  row1          (1,       1,     1)
  row2          (2,       1,     2)
  row3          (3,       1,     3)
  row4          (4,       2,     1)
  row5          (5,       3,     1)
  ```
- Table 3:

  ```
  keywords (keyword_id, keyword_name) // keyword_id is set to primary 
  row1          (1,       "key1")
  row2          (2,       "key2")
  row3          (3,       "key3")
  row4          (4,       "key4")
  row5          (5,       "key5")
  ```

I would like to make a query that returns all items that contain certain keywords AND also don't contain some other keywords.

If you look at the table data above you can see that:

```
Item 1 contains keywords with ids: 1,2 and 3; 
Item 2 contains keyword with id: 1 
item 3 contains keyword_id =1
```

So I need a query that will return all items that contain **key1** (keyword_id=1) and DON'T contain **key3** (keyword_id=3). In this exmaple the query should return key2 (keyword_id=2), key3 (keyword_id=3).

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM items a
JOIN item_keywords b ON b.item_id = a.item_id
WHERE b.keyword_id = 1
   AND b.keyword_id != 3
```

But this doesn't work properly because the query returns key1,key2 and key3. The answer should be: key2 and key3. What would be the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: If you have a record with keyword_id = 1, it can never also have keyword_id = 3.  Are you sure you are describing what you are looking for?

Comment: and why couldn't it have keyword_id = 1 and keyword_id = 3 ? item_keywords is a linking table between keywords and items (i didn't describe the items table because it isn't relative for this problem)

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now, Sorry.  You do not need the `Keywords` table in the description of your problem then.

Comment: @blejzz You should rephrase your question, the words you use to describe the results are very misleading and you should also clarify the fact that there is another table. It took me a will to figure out what you were trying to achieve

Comment: @blejzz I made an attempt to rephrase your question.  If I am incorrect, I apologize.  My answer is based off this assumption

Comment: update my question, hope it makes more sense than before.. if not i can try to explain it even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN item_keywords AS ik ON i.item_id = ik.item_id
WHERE keyword_id = 1
   AND ik.item_id NOT IN
   (
      SELECT item_id
      FROM item_keywords
      WHERE keyword_id = 3
   )
```

[Example of query working:](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120274/)

Comment: @blejzz I have updated my query for your tables, as well as provided you a link to a working example.